# Creating a Chart Is VERY Slow

Tags: excel, vba

I'm inserting charts into a worksheet using VBA.
The first chart gets added very quickly (a fraction of a second) but thereafter it takes at least 20 seconds to create any subsequent charts and I'm not sure why it is so slow.

```
Dim newChartObj As ChartObject
Set newChartObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(endRange.Left, endRange.Offset(2, 0).Top, 360, 240)
```

The second line of the code above is where the delay occurs. At this point I haven't even added a series of data. When the chart object is finally created, I go ahead and start adding the series, formatting, etc. and all of this happens very quickly.

Th spreadsheet itself is large (about 20Mb, with a bit over 100k rows of data and 60+ columns) but not really huge. I also have no delay problem if I insert a chart manually.

If anyone has any hints as to how to overcome this I'd be very grateful!

Comment: "*Th spreadsheet itself is large*": This is probably why. Try setting `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` at the beginning of your code and resetting it with `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` at the end.

Comment: VBA itself has Java like speed, so, most times it's because Excell doesn't handle the requests well (or bug in you codes), actually, Excell is so slow in handling changes that one may think manual editing is faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently ran into this same problem with ChartObjects.Add() being very slow. My findings may or may not be helpful to others, but I figured I would at least share what I found as I believe it relates to the response from @Marcel.

I my case I had two sheets where I was using the ChartObjects.Add() call. On one sheet, the call executed instantly, on the other it took about a minute. On a hunch, I decided to call Worksheet.UsedRange.Address to see what value was being returned.

On the fast executing sheet, I got something like $A$1:$Z$100. But for the slow executing sheet, I got something like $A:$Z. This meant that it was actually using ~1.4 million rows, even though the actual data was much less. I believe this was because we used Range.EntireColumn to set some formatting. We did not have this formatting on the fast sheet.

In the end we changed our code to prevent it from setting formatting 'infinitely' and the execution of the ChartObjects.Add became instantaneous.

Using a filter like @Marcel may be viable or you may need to change your code like we did if you are getting UsedRange with entire columns instead of set rows.

Comment: Ha! I suspect you have found a solution to my problem. I haven't been using this for around 18 months but when I finally located the spreadsheet and the code, I did indeed find that I was initially formatting entire columns. I removed this formatting and adding the carts become a LOT quicker. It's certainly not instantaneous but it's much, much quicker and certainly acceptable (and the latest dataset is now over 300,000 rows). I'll need to test this more extensively but it seems like you have found the underlying cause of the problem.

Comment: Glad to help. It was certainly an odd behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Disable everything before running the code

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False


Dim newChartObj As ChartObject
Set newChartObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(endRange.Left, _
    endRange.Offset(2, 0).Top, 360, 240)


Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.CutCopyMode = True
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, abdullah. Actually I ad tried setting Calculation to Manual and turning off screen updating. But I hadn't switched off EnableEvents or CutCopyMode. However, I've just tried with all 4 together and it doesn't make a difference.
Reducing the size of the spreadsheet which Super Symmetry suggested may be the problem, does speed up things. But it doesn't explain why inserting a chart manually is not a problem.

Comment: Try using shapes.addChart    like   ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(251, xlPie).Select
 ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Trades 2021'!$B$4:$B$11")

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, abdullah. But I've just tried that and if anything it seems to be even slower! The first chart is always quick but subsequent ones are really slow (20-30 seconds.)

Answer (score 0):

I had extreme performance problems with:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
```

The problem is the amount of Data in the table (10'000 - 500'000 Lines).
Disabling "everything" did not help in my case.

My Solution is, to reduce the displayed amount of lines, by using the autofilter:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B:B").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="1"
```

By only displaying every 1'000th line.

Then add the chart, set the DataSource, and configure the chart, ...
Then undo the autofilter.
In my case, this reduced the used time by more than a factor of 10.